# upload multiple files in one request Dropzone sending two requests

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, dropzone.js

I am trying to send multiple files in one request using DropZone js.

Here's my code :

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

var myDropzone = new Dropzone('#upload-Invoices', {       
    paramName: "files", 
    maxFilesize: 3.0, 
    maxFiles: 4,
    parallelUploads: 10000,
    uploadMultiple: true,
    autoProcessQueue: false
});

$('#btnUpload').on('click', function () {
    myDropzone.processQueue();
});
```

Controller :

```
public void FileUpload( IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> file )
{
    // Do Something
}
```

View:

```
<form action="/Index/FileUpload"
      class="dropzone"
      id="upload-Invoices" data-ajax-method="POST" data-ajax="true">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File to Server" id="btnUpload">
</form>
```

The files are being received although in diferrent requests, I want to send all files in one request, the Dropzone page has an option for it although it does not work. 
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Issue was that I was using an input `type="submit"` which would do another post by itself, changing it to type `button` worked.

Comment: Weird I have the exact same issue but input type=button doesn't fix it for me. I had to add parallelUploads: 10 to get it working, because paralledUploads defaults to 2 files only.

Answer (score 14):

you can use uploadMultiple property default value false change it to true

```js
$(".dropzone").dropzone({
            // autoQueue:false,
            parallelUploads:10,
            uploadMultiple:true,
```

https://www.dropzonejs.com/#config-uploadMultiple

Comment: *"you can use uploadMultiple property"*... the example code in the question already has `uploadMultiple: true`.

Answer (score 5):

Had the same problem, just add autoDiscover: false, to your dropzone options and it should work!

My options are like this:

```
Dropzone.options.UploadZone = {        
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    autoDiscover: false,
    uploadMultiple: true,
    parallelUploads: 10,
    maxFiles: 10,
    acceptedFiles: ".jpeg,.jpg,.png",
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    ...
```

With autoProcessQueue: false and uploadMultiple: true: for each 2 files i was getting a request.

Then I added parallelUploads: 10 and maxFiles: 10 and i don't know why but my first  2 files started uploading as soon as i putted them on the dropzone, even with autoProcessQueue: false.

Then I just add autoDiscover: false and everything worked fine from there!

good look!

Answer (score 4):

I was also seeing multiple POSTs with 2 files being sent at a time (so, for instance, 2 separate POSTs for 4 files total).

I found the solution [here](https://github.com/rowanwins/vue-dropzone/issues/41): increasing `parallelUploads`. I now create the dropzone in the following way:

```
var myDropzone = new Dropzone('div#dz', {
  url: 'http://httpbin.org/post',
  uploadMultiple: true,
  parallelUploads: 10
});
```

Comment: Probably also good to set `maxFiles: 10` so the user does not go over your parallel limit and trigger another HTTP request.

Answer (score 2):

The `enqueueForUpload` property is deprecated and you should use `autoProcessQueue` instead. My hunch is that, since `enqueueForUpload` is no longer used and you don't set `autoProcessQueue` to `false`, the DropZone.js assumes that you want to send each file, as it is dropped on the component.

You should remove `enqueueForUpload: false`, set `autoProcessQueue: false` and after you've selected (i.e. dropped) all the files you need to upload, call the `.processQueue()` function, as described in the [documentation](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#enqueuing-file-uploads).

Comment: That's really weird. Sorry, I don't have any more ideas.

Comment: However, one has files in the post, the second request does not.

Comment: Are you posting the form as well? I'm no DropZone.js expert but it could be that the `processQueue()` function posts the form. And another thing, what happens if you set `enctype="multipart/form-data"`on your form?

Comment: Its some type of encoding and is necessary when you are dealing with uploads

Comment: That's the standard way of uploading files in ASP.MVC. That's why I asked if you tried setting the correct `enctype`.

Comment: Was this resolved?  i'm getting two requests as well. one with files, one without

Comment: I solved this by increasing `parallelUploads` -- see other answer posted to this question

Answer (score 0):

I can see it is very old post, however, I will answer hoping it might help someone.

2 requests

> 1. OPTIONS - no files
> 2. POST - with files

Chrome will do a **pre-flight request(OPTIONS)** to look for CORS headers. It is a standard which almost all latest browsers follow.