# Simple Dropzone implementation in ASP.Net MVC - How can I get data in the Controller?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, drag-and-drop, dropzone.js, dropzone

I am trying to implement Dropzone.js in ASP.Net MVC. I tried everything but somehow I cannot receive the dropped file in the controller. The variable is just NULL.

My View looks like this:

```html
    <h2>DropZoneUp</h2>
    <form action='@Url.Action("DropZoneUpload")'class="dropzone"id="my-awesome-dropzone">
    </form>
    
    <script src="~/Scripts/dropzone.js"></script>
```

My Controller looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DropZoneUpload(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
{
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        string filePath = Guid.NewGuid() + Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
        file.SaveAs(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/ExcelNDropUpload"), filePath));
    }
    return Json("fileupload successfully");
}
```

The Controller actually gets called from the View. But the "IEnumerable files" are Null. 
Does anybody have an idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

best regards
BeardyBear

Comment: Try adding `multipart/form-data` like this: `<form action='@Url.Action("DropZoneUpload")' class="dropzone" id="my-awesome-dropzone" enctype="multipart/form-data">`.

Comment: Hey Tetsuya, thanks for your answer. But it is still null. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Have you already set `autoDiscover = false` & `autoProcessQueue: false` to your Dropzone instance? Check [here](https://www.dropzonejs.com/#configuration) for possible configurations (also provide related JS codes if you can).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're forgot to include `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute and using `method="post"` because the target controller action has `HttpPostAttribute` (by default if you don't specify HTTP method in the form tag it will [sets as GET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314401/what-is-the-default-form-http-method)). The correct code should be like this:

```
<form action='@Url.Action("DropZoneUpload")' class="dropzone" id="my-awesome-dropzone" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
   <!-- other form elements -->
</form>
```

Or with `BeginForm` helper:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("DropZoneUpload", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "dropzone", id = "my-awesome-dropzone", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @* other form elements *@
}
```

The `multipart/form-data` is necessary if you want to post any file together with other input element values.

Answer (score 1):

It will be great if you post your post/submit method of that form.
I found some people try to do the same thing as you, you might try to refer this question:
[upload-multiple-files-in-one-request-dropzone-sending-two-requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28021984/upload-multiple-files-in-one-request-dropzone-sending-two-requests)